# Where should I put the file `inconsolata.sty'

Tags: packages

When I run the `R CMD check MYpackagePATH` form a terminal on the package directory, then the error said that

```
! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.
```

So, I download the file `inconsolata.zip`. But I am not sure **where should I put the file.**

Comment: If you are using it only for this one document then put it in the same directory If you think you will use it often, and have sufficient permissions, put it in the `tex/latex` subdirectory of TEXMFLOCAL. Otherwise, put it where ever you like and add the directory to TEXINPUTS. (To find the TEXMFLOCAL use `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL` from the command-line. You set TEXNPUTS in your `.bashrc` file or equivalent.)

Comment: `inconsolata` is a standard package which is provided by both MiKTeX and TeX Live, so you can use these TeX distributions to install `inconsolata` instead of (much more difficult) installing manually.

Comment: Thank you @JouleV for edtion, my English is poor, it helps me very much.  I am not sure but my installation does not go well.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. I will try. This is only quick response to say thank you.

Comment: I put `inconsolata.sty` as `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\insconsolata.sty`. Is it OK ?

Comment: Yes, that's a good location if you can't install using MikTeX or equivalent.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew , I got confidence from your reply!!   But,..`R CMD check` also launched the same error...

Comment: Sure that you not do have already inconsolata.sty elsewhere? Try to make a simple latex document using inconsolata. If it works, then the problem is in the R package, not in the MikTeX side.

Comment: Thank you @Fran. I tried to compile some TeX file which require `Rd.sty`. I put the `Rd.sty` in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\Rd.sty` but TeX works and R studio cannot reflect its existence, But if I put `Rd.sty` in the same directory including TeX file, then it goes well. So, I cannot understand why TeXworks  cannot detect the sty files.